# Bootstrap data-toggle and scrollIntoView for all areas

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image map with multiple areas and each area has a href ID. Clicking on an area on the image collapses a div below the image, and clicking on the same area again closes the collapsed div.

I'm trying to get the div to scrollIntoView when clicked, and I managed to do it with

```
    $('#A00Info').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        document.getElementById('A00Info').scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
```

Now, this works to a certain degree. When I click on the #A00Info area, it collapses its div below the image and scrolls it into view.

My problem is that I have 4 image maps with numerous areas and I don't want to copy and paste the script for each div.

How do I write a function/script that looks for an area that has been clicked on and then looks for a corresponding div, collapses it and scrolls it into view?

I have made two attempts,

```
               $('area[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
               var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
               target.scrollIntoView();

           });
```

and

```
            $('area[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            document.getElementById('href').scrollIntoView();
        });
```

but I have not been successful. I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript and a novice programmer. I would be very helpful for any help or guidance.

EDIT: This is my HTML

a pane with the map and its areas

```
...<div id="groundfloor" class="tab-pane fade">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <img src="FloorPlanGround.png" alt="" usemap="#groundfloormap">
                                    <map name="groundfloormap" id="groundfloormap">
                                        <area data-toggle="collapse" alt="" title="" href="#A00Info" shape="rect" coords="220,203,344,322" />
                                        <area data-toggle="collapse" alt="" title="" href="#A07Info" shape="rect" coords="288,129,343,152" />...
```

and the divs that open when an area has been clicked

```
...<div class="container-fluid">
                                <div id="A00Info" class="text-center hidden">
                                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                        <div class="row1 col-lg-12 text-left" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                                            <h2 style="text-decoration: underline; margin-bottom: 1px;">A00</h2>...
```

Comment: do u have your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Tried to make a fiddle but no success there either

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is in the same boat as I was, I managed to do what I wanted with the following code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div:hidden").on({
                'shown.bs.collapse': function(){
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 20
                    }, 'slow'); 
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                },
                'hidden.bs.collapse': function(){
                    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }  
            });
        });
```

I've replaced scrollIntoView with animate ({scrollTop}), tweaked it a little bit, and I got even better behaviour than I was aiming for (the page smoothscrolls into the div that opens on click instead of just jumping it into view). Also, I learned a little bit about jQuery selectors (had to select div:hidden in this case so it'd work, instead of looking for area[href="#"]).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, here in this example. `link_` is all `a` tags starting with `link_`. So you can use it as `id` get and `href` and scroll.

so your `ids` can be `link_#A00Info` or `link_#A00Details`. it will work on both `ids`

or better you provide **HTML** code as well.

```
      $('[id^="link_"]').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(event) {
        var dataValue = $(this).attr('href');
        $(dataValue).scrollIntoView();
      });
```

Comment: I have tried this but was unsuccessful, where do I add the `link_`s? I've added HTML to my original post

Comment: Text me on my Skype ID 'Indian.pie' . I will fix it.

Comment: Fixed in my post, just below - thanks again for helping me